# Deixar Input ao lado do Label

Tags: html, jquery, html5, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

### Como alinhar os inputs com o label

---

Boa tarde, possuo um formulário dinâmico, ele é feito utilizando Bootstrap e os `inputs/Labels` vem conforme os dados do banco, esta tudo correto, porém na exibição os `inputs` estão ficando abaixo do `Label` e não ao lado como era para ser.

[image: Como esta a tela atualmente]

---

### Jquery que monta meu formulário

```
$.getJSON($('#base-url').val() + '/atleta/get_input_area_avaliar',
            function(data) {
                for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) { 
                        form += '<div class=\"col-md-12\">';
                        if(i == 0 || data[i]['descricao_tecnica'] != data[i-1]['descricao_tecnica']){ 
                            form += '<p style=\"font-weight: bold; font-size:18px; background-color: #0D80BF; color:white;\" class=\"text-center\"><span>'+data[i]['descricao_tecnica']+'</span></p>'; 
                        }
                        form += '<div><label for=\"'+data[i]['cod_area_avaliar_item']+'\">'+data[i]['descricao_item']+':</label></div>';

                        form += '<select style=\"width:65px;\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"item_'+ data[i]['cod_area_avaliar_item'] +'\" name=\"item_'+ data[i]['cod_area_avaliar_item'] +'\">';
                        form += '<option value=\"--\" disabled selected>---</option>';
                        form += '<option value=\"10\">10</option>';
                        form += '<option value=\"9\">9</option>';
                        form += '<option value=\"8\">8</option>';
                        form += '<option value=\"7\">7</option>';
                        form += '<option value=\"6\">6</option>';
                        form += '<option value=\"5\">5</option>';
                        form += '<option value=\"4\">4</option>';
                        form += '<option value=\"3\">3</option>';
                        form += '<option value=\"2\">2</option>';
                        form += '<option value=\"1\">1</option>';
                        form += '</select>';
                        form += '<br>';
                        form += '</div>';
                }
                $('#frmNovaAvaliacao #inputs_avaliacao').html(form);
            });
```

---

### HTML onde o form é inserido

```
<div id="frmAvaliacaoItem" style="overflow-y: auto;" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <form onsubmit="salvar_area_avaliacao_item(); return false;" style="margin-bottom:0">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 id="myModalLabel"></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="alert" style="display:none;"></div>


            <div class="col-md-12">                                        
                <input id="cod_area_avaliar_item" type="hidden" name="cod_area_avaliar_item" value="null"/>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label for="descricao">Descrição</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="descricao" id="descricao" required/>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                <br>
                    <table id="tbl-area_avaliar_item" class="table table-sm table-hover">
                        <thead>

                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Tipo de avaliação técnica</th>
                                <th scope="col">Descrição</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Salvar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

---

### HTML Renderizado

Não estou utilizando `css` externo, somente `bootstrap`

```
<div id="frmNovaAvaliacao" style="overflow-y: auto; display: block;" class="modal fade in" role="dialog" aria-hidden="false">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <form class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="salva_avaliacao(); return false;" style="margin-bottom:0">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 id="myModalLabel"></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
                    <input style="float:right; border-radius:2px" type="text" name="data_avaliacao" id="data_avaliacao" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"> </div>
                <input id="cod_escola" type="hidden" name="cod_escola" value="301">
                <input id="cod_atleta_area_avaliar" type="hidden" name="cod_atleta_area_avaliar" value="0">
                <input id="cod_atleta" type="hidden" name="cod_atleta" value="353">
                <!-- Montar formulario pelo JS -->
                <div id="inputs_avaliacao_hidden"></div>
                <div id="inputs_avaliacao">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size:18px; background-color: #0D80BF; color:white;" class="text-center"><span>Aspecto Fisico</span></p>
                        <label for="45">Velocidade:</label>
                        <select style="width:65px;" class="form-control" id="item_45" name="item_45">
                            <option value="--" disabled="" selected="">---</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label for="20">Força:</label>
                        <select style="width:65px;" class="form-control" id="item_20" name="item_20">
                            <option value="--" disabled="" selected="">---</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label for="19">Biotipo:</label>
                        <select style="width:65px;" class="form-control" id="item_19" name="item_19">
                            <option value="--" disabled="" selected="">---</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size:18px; background-color: #0D80BF; color:white;" class="text-center"><span>Habilidade motora</span></p>
                        <label for="52">Condução/controle de bola:</label>
                        <select style="width:65px;" class="form-control" id="item_52" name="item_52">
                            <option value="--" disabled="" selected="">---</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label for="53">Desarme:</label>
                        <select style="width:65px;" class="form-control" id="item_53" name="item_53">
                            <option value="--" disabled="" selected="">---</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label for="55">Passe:</label>
                        <select style="width:65px;" class="form-control" id="item_55" name="item_55">
                            <option value="--" disabled="" selected="">---</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label for="56">Drible:</label>
                        <select style="width:65px;" class="form-control" id="item_56" name="item_56">
                            <option value="--" disabled="" selected="">---</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label for="57">Chute:</label>
                        <select style="width:65px;" class="form-control" id="item_57" name="item_57">
                            <option value="--" disabled="" selected="">---</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label for="58">Cabeceio:</label>
                        <select style="width:65px;" class="form-control" id="item_58" name="item_58">
                            <option value="--" disabled="" selected="">---</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size:18px; background-color: #0D80BF; color:white;" class="text-center"><span>Inteligencia de jogo</span></p>
                        <label for="23">Tomada de decisão:</label>
                        <select style="width:65px;" class="form-control" id="item_23" name="item_23">
                            <option value="--" disabled="" selected="">---</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label for="51">Tática individual:</label>
                        <select style="width:65px;" class="form-control" id="item_51" name="item_51">
                            <option value="--" disabled="" selected="">---</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label for="22">Criatividade:</label>
                        <select style="width:65px;" class="form-control" id="item_22" name="item_22">
                            <option value="--" disabled="" selected="">---</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label for="28">Liderança:</label>
                        <select style="width:65px;" class="form-control" id="item_28" name="item_28">
                            <option value="--" disabled="" selected="">---</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label for="50">Competitividade:</label>
                        <select style="width:65px;" class="form-control" id="item_50" name="item_50">
                            <option value="--" disabled="" selected="">---</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size:18px; background-color: #0D80BF; color:white;" class="text-center"><span>Teste de avaliacao</span></p>
                        <label for="62">Item 2:</label>
                        <select style="width:65px;" class="form-control" id="item_62" name="item_62">
                            <option value="--" disabled="" selected="">---</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label for="63">Item 1:</label>
                        <select style="width:65px;" class="form-control" id="item_63" name="item_63">
                            <option value="--" disabled="" selected="">---</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p style="font-weight: bold;">Legenda: </p>
                <p style="font-size:12px;"> <em>(10)</em> Excelente A - <em>(9)</em> Excelente B - <em>(8)</em> Bom A - <em>(7)</em> Bom B - <em>(6)</em> Regular A - <em>(5)</em> Regular B - <em>(4)</em> Fraco A - <em>(3)</em> Fraci B - <em>(2)</em> Péssimo A - <em>(1)</em> Péssimo B </p>
                <div class="form-group" style="margin: 30px 0 30px 0;">
                    <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size:18px; background-color: #0D80BF; color:white;" class="text-center"><span>Relatório aprovação/reprovação</span></p>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="relatorio" name="relatorio"></textarea>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label for="treinador">Treinador</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="treinador" id="treinador"> </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label for="preparador">Preparador Fisico</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="preparador" id="preparador"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label for="supervisor">Supervisor</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="supervisor" id="supervisor"> </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label for="coordenador">Coordenador Técnico</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="coordenador" id="coordenador"> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="modal-footer" style="margin-top:20%;">
                <button id="btn_salvar_avaliacao" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tenho um ambiente que possa testar seu código, mas posso te garantir que ao colocar a `label` dentro de uma `div` como vc fez aqui:

```
form += '<div><label for=\"'+data[i]['cod_area_avaliar_item']+'\">'+data[i]['descricao_item']+':</label></div>';
```

A `div` vai fazer com que a "linha quebre", pois uma `div` ocupa 100% da largura da tela por ser um elemento do tipo bloco e não deixa que nada fique ao lado dele. Assim com a `label` dentro da `div` a linha quebra e joga o `select` para linha de baixo. Para arrumar tire a `label` de dentro da `div`

```
form += '<label for=\"'+data[i]['cod_area_avaliar_item']+'\">'+data[i]['descricao_item']+':</label>';
```

---

**EDIT**

Mas como vc está usando Bootrstrap 3, o correto é seguir o que diz a documentação com vc pode consultar aqui: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-inline

> Add `.form-inline` to your `form` (which doesn't have to be a `<form>`) for
>   left-aligned and inline-block controls. **This only applies to forms
>   within viewports that are at least 768px wide**.

*PORTUGUÊS
"Adicione `.form-inline` ao seu `form` (que não precisa ser um `<form>`) para controles alinhados à esquerda e em bloco. **Isso se aplica somente a formulários em viewports com pelo menos 768px de largura.**"*

*Mas tenha em mente que em telas menores que 768px o forme sempre vai ficar com o label acima o outro elemento abaixo*

---

**EDIT2**

Acredito que algumas coisas não estão funcionando pq estão em desacordo com a documentação, tipo alguns elementos precisam ser filhos diretos de outros etc... Mas vc pode usar a ideia do `form-horizontal`, dessa forma vc separa a `label` em uma `col-xs-2`, e o select em outra `col-xs-10` Isso vai garantir que um vai ficar do lado do outro.

Outra forma é colocar na `label` `float-left` assim que vier abaixo flutua ao lado da `label`

Fiz os dois modelos no código abaixo

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

  
    <div id="frmNovaAvaliacao" style="overflow-y: auto; display: block;" class="modal fade in" role="dialog" aria-hidden="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <form class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="salva_avaliacao(); return false;" style="margin-bottom:0">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        <h3 id="myModalLabel"></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
                            <input style="float:right; border-radius:2px" type="text" name="data_avaliacao" id="data_avaliacao" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"> </div>
                        <input id="cod_escola" type="hidden" name="cod_escola" value="301">
                        <input id="cod_atleta_area_avaliar" type="hidden" name="cod_atleta_area_avaliar" value="0">
                        <input id="cod_atleta" type="hidden" name="cod_atleta" value="353">
                        <!-- Montar formulario pelo JS -->
                        <div id="inputs_avaliacao_hidden"></div>
                        <div id="inputs_avaliacao">
                            <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size:18px; background-color: #0D80BF; color:white;" class="text-center"><span>Aspecto Fisico</span></p>
                                <div class="col-xs-2"><label for="45">Velocidade:</label></div>
                                <div class="col-xs-10">
                                  <select style="width:65px;" class="form-control" id="item_45" name="item_45">
                                      <option value="--" disabled="" selected="">---</option>
                                      <option value="10">10</option>
                                      <option value="9">9</option>
                                      <option value="8">8</option>
                                      <option value="7">7</option>
                                      <option value="6">6</option>
                                      <option value="5">5</option>
                                      <option value="4">4</option>
                                      <option value="3">3</option>
                                      <option value="2">2</option>
                                      <option value="1">1</option>
                                  </select>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label for="20" style="float:left">Força:</label>
                                <select style="width:65px;" class="form-control" id="item_20" name="item_20">
                                    <option value="--" disabled="" selected="">---</option>
                                    <option value="10">10</option>
                                    <option value="9">9</option>
                                    <option value="8">8</option>
                                    <option value="7">7</option>
                                    <option value="6">6</option>
                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                </select>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label for="63">Item 1:</label>
                                <select style="width:65px;" class="form-control" id="item_63" name="item_63">
                                    <option value="--" disabled="" selected="">---</option>
                                    <option value="10">10</option>
                                    <option value="9">9</option>
                                    <option value="8">8</option>
                                    <option value="7">7</option>
                                    <option value="6">6</option>
                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                </select>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p style="font-weight: bold;">Legenda: </p>
                        <p style="font-size:12px;"> <em>(10)</em> Excelente A - <em>(9)</em> Excelente B - <em>(8)</em> Bom A - <em>(7)</em> Bom B - <em>(6)</em> Regular A - <em>(5)</em> Regular B - <em>(4)</em> Fraco A - <em>(3)</em> Fraci B - <em>(2)</em> Péssimo A - <em>(1)</em> Péssimo B </p>
                        <div class="form-group" style="margin: 30px 0 30px 0;">
                            <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size:18px; background-color: #0D80BF; color:white;" class="text-center"><span>Relatório aprovação/reprovação</span></p>
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="relatorio" name="relatorio"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="treinador">Treinador</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="treinador" id="treinador"> </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="preparador">Preparador Fisico</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="preparador" id="preparador"> </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="supervisor">Supervisor</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="supervisor" id="supervisor"> </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="coordenador">Coordenador Técnico</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="coordenador" id="coordenador"> </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="modal-footer" style="margin-top:20%;">
                        <button id="btn_salvar_avaliacao" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Já removi a div, porém sem sucesso :(

Comment: Pelo inspecionar, o select esta ocupando 100%, mas não consigo diminuir isso.

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti já sei o que é, vou editar está na documentação do Bootstrap inclusive

Comment: Já havia removido a div amigo, mas sem sucesso !

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti veja o link do Edit

Comment: Já havia acrescentado as tags `form-inline` porém sem sucesso, estou testando na tela do meu computador mesmo e continua errado :(, os campos de label estão ocupando pouco espaço, os de select estão ocupando todo o espaço deles mesmo sendo pequenos, talvez seja essa a razão dele quebrar a linha. Como eu poderia redimensionar esses `select`

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti cara copia o códig HTML conforme aparece no Browser, da um Ctrl+U e pega o código já renderizado e cola ai na sua pergunta, inclua tb o que tiver de CSS, só assim vai dar para te dar uma resposta precisa...

Comment: Vale lembrar que também têm os [`forms horizontais`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-horizontal) que também deixam o `input` na mesma linha que o `label`. Só resta saber se você quer todos numa linha ou cada dupla label-input em sua linha.

Comment: Corrigi agora quando vi teu comentário na outra resposta. hahah

Comment: @fernandosavio Boa

Comment: @fernandosavio Cada dupla `label/input' em uma linha.
Editei a pergunta conforme solicitado @hugocsl

Comment: Aí @hugocsl, é o form horizontal mesmo. Só editar o exemplo e correr para o abraço

Comment: @fernandosavio removi o `form-control` e com o `form-horizontal` consegui, porém os `select` ficaram pequenos e perderam o estilo do bootstrap.

Comment: Se tu ler a documentação que linkei no comentário acima verá que a classe `.form-horizontal` deve ser colocada no `<form>` enquanto a classe `.form-control` deve ser colocada nos  `<input>`, `<textarea>` e `<select>`.

Comment: Quando coloco a coloco a classe `form-horizontal` no form e `form-control` nos `select`. Ela não funciona.

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti olha o Edit 2, pode te ajudar a resolver a situação...

Comment: @fernandosavio acho que não funciona pq alguns elementos precisam ser filhos diretos de outros, o que não acontece na estrutura dele...

Answer (score 1):

Basta declarar a classe `form-inline` em seu formulário.

Resultado:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<br><br>
<form class="form-inline"> 
  
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputPassword6">Password</label>
       <input type="password" id="inputPassword6" class="form-control mx-sm-3" aria-describedby="passwordHelpInline">
    </div>    
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="my-1 mr-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">Preference</label>
  <select class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">
    <option selected>Choose...</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
    </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="my-1 mr-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">Settings</label>
  <select class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">
    <option selected>Choose...</option>
    <option value="1">Exemplo</option>
    <option value="2">Exemplo</option>
    <option value="3">Exemplo</option>
  </select>
  </div>
  
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Exemplo retirado da [documentação](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-inline).